# foreach is not working in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP but I need to know, how can i get the `title` in `volumeinfo` in php?

```
Array
(
    [kind] => books#volumes
    [totalItems] => 595
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => books#volume
                    [id] => Aaug_RnI-xQC
                    [etag] => E1EIADudeHY
                    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/Aaug_RnI-xQC
                    [volumeInfo] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => The Irresistible Rise of Harry Potter
                            [authors] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Andrew Blake
                                )

                            [publisher] => Verso
                            [publishedDate] => 2002
                            [description] => As the British state begins to unravel, and as journalists compete to pronounce on the death...
```

Help me please.

Comment: `foreach($array['items'] as $items) { echo $items['volumnInfo']['title']; }`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post an example of the code you've attempted to use, and any errors you might have seen as a result. We could give you the answer, but it's better if we help guide you to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try for single value

```
echo $array['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['title'];
```

or use `foreach`

```
foreach($array['items'] as $items) { 
  echo $items['volumeInfo']['title']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is held in `$array`

- Loop through `items`
- Echo `volumnInfo.title`

```
foreach($array['items'] as $items) { 
   echo $items['volumnInfo']['title'] . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code

```
foreach($array['items'] as $item) 
{ 
   echo $item['volumnInfo']['title']; 
}
```